# Steps to solving a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider differential equation  for $u = u(x, t)$:

$$ u_{xx}-u_t = 0$$

with $0 <x<L$ and $t < 0$ and initial conditions: $u(0, t) = u(L, t)=0$ for $t > 0$ and $u(x, 0) = f(x)$, where $f$ is $C^1$ and L-periodic.

Find $u(x,t)$

I'm preping for a complex analysis exam and I have to be able to solve that kind a problem.

How does One approach this problem and what are the steps to solving it.

Comment: What kind of complex analysis class are you taking that you need to solve such a PDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main approach for such a problem will be separation of variables, I wont type all the steps since you can find these in this pdf [link](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m267/heatSln.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjK0vy3rbnUAhVLPVAKHfIqCFIQFggcMAA&usg=AFQjCNGHJwKjiwLAZ4a27cxvnAX3u6e9HA)